# Кодировка request в Node

Tags: node.js

Есть Node версии 6.11.3 есть простейший код который принимает реквест от браузера.

```
if(req.method == "POST" && req.url == '/') {
    let post;
    let porto ="porto onwire";
    req.on('data', chunk =>{
        post = iconv.decode( chunk, "utf8" );
        console.log(post);
        console.log(typeof(post));
    });
```

Где req - реквест отправленый браузером и код просто выводит тело запроса в консоль. 
Так вот если я отправляюь форму с методом POST и в форме есть киоррилица, то получаю ответ

```
firstname=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0&lastname=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD&gender=male&email=s%40g&group=nameGroup&scoreEge=234&yearBirth=456&livingSite=location
```

Если я отправляю прямо из браузера:

```
fetch("/", {"method":"POST", body:JSON.stringify({"trap":"ах ты ж курва"})})
```

То консоль прекрасно выводит киррилицу - `{"trap":"ах ты ж курва"}`

Comment: А вы отправляйте [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) вместо JSON.stringify - тогда оба способа будут давать одинаковый результат.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov , хм, но мне нужно получить корректную киррилицу из формы, лол, а не одинаковый ответ. Я даже в какую сторону гуглить не знаю.

Comment: в сторону формата form data

Comment: `decodeURI('firstname=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0&lastname=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD')`
> "firstname=рома&lastname=нерон"

Comment: @Dart  ОООО , ты мой бриллиант!! Спасибо, я уже думал что лоб об стену расшибу. Я тебе очень благодарен.